# no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium

I'm new to selenium please help. Entire code:

```
<document>
    <html class="ext-strict ext-strict x-viewport" lang="en" style="">
        <head>
          <body id="ext-gen3" class="ServiceDeskPage sfxConsole ext-gecko ext-gecko3 sfdcBody brandQuaternaryBgr x-border-layout-ct" onfocus="if(this.bodyOnFocus)bodyOnFocus();" onload="if(this.bodyOnLoad)bodyOnLoad();" onbeforeunload="if(this.bodyOnBeforeUnload){var s=bodyOnBeforeUnload();if(s)return s;}" onunload="if(this.bodyOnUnload)bodyOnUnload();">
             <div id="ServiceDeskHeader" class=" x-panel sd_header x-border-panel x-panel-noborder" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1366px;">
             <div id="serviceDeskFooter" class=" sd_footer widget_right_aligned x-border-panel x-hide-display x-box-layout-ct" style="height: 35px; background: rgb(167, 169, 172) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
             <div id="hotkey_focus_effect" style="display:none"/>
             <div id="servicedesk" class=" miniviewtab_enabled x-border-panel x-border-layout-ct" style="left: 0px; top: 75px; width: 1366px; height: 202px;">

             <!-- Main Body Starts Here -->

             <form id="sessiontimeout" onsubmit="if (window.ffInAlert) { return false; }" name="sessiontimeout" method="post">
             <a class="navSkipLink zen-skipLink zen-assistiveText" href="#skiplink">Skip to main content</a>
             <form name="HistoryForm" method="POST" action="">
             <div id="auraElementContainer" class="hiddenAuraElementContainer">
             <div id="ext-comp-1002" class="x-tip" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20002; visibility: hidden; display: none;">
             <div id="ServiceDeskHeader-xsplit" class="x-layout-split x-layout-split-north x-splitbar-v-custom-logo x-splitbar-disabled" style="visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: 77px; width: 1366px;">
             <div id="ext-gen35" class="dd-drop-indicator" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
             <div id="ext-gen51" class="dd-drop-indicator" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
             <div id="ext-gen55" class=" x-unselectable x-splitbar-proxy x-splitbar-proxy-h" style="-moz-user-select: none;"/>
             <div id="ext-gen63" class="x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
             <div id="ext-gen86" class="dd-drop-indicator" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
             <div id="undefinedHover" class="individualPalette lookupHoverDetail lookupHoverDetailLoading lookupHoverDetailOverridable">
             <iframe title="sessionserver" style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px;" src="https://test.salesforce.com/login/sessionserver202.html"/>
             <div id="ext-gen113" class="x-shadow" style="z-index: 14999; left: 1px; top: 40px; width: 258px; height: 240px; display: none;">
             <div id="navigator-sbmenu" class="x-menu x-menu-floating x-layer x-hide-offsets" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; width: 250px;">
             <a id="ext-gen94" class="x-menu-focus" tabindex="-1" onclick="return false;" href="#"/>
             <ul id="ext-gen95" class="x-menu-list" style="height: 224px;">
             <li id="x-menu-el-nav-tab-0" class="x-menu-list-item">
             <li id="x-menu-el-nav-tab-1" class="x-menu-list-item">

//On mouse click this element should be selected out of the list items mentioned.

             <**a id="nav-tab-1" class="x-menu-item accountMru standardObject sd-nav-menu-item" href="#" unselectable="on" hidefocus="true"**>
             </li>
             <li id="x-menu-el-nav-tab-2" class="x-menu-list-item">
             <li id="x-menu-el-nav-tab-3" class="x-menu-list-item">
             <li id="x-menu-el-nav-tab-4" class="x-menu-list-item">
             <li id="x-menu-el-nav-tab-5" class="x-menu-list-item">
             <li id="x-menu-el-nav-tab-6" class="x-menu-list-item">
             <li id="x-menu-el-nav-tab-7" class="x-menu-list-item">
             </ul>
         </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</document>
```

How can I select the xpath for the element highlighted in Bold? I've tried a lot of examples but unfortunately none worked as expected.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath for this element is very simple actually

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id=nav-tab-1]");
```

Alternatively you can just use a By.id selector to select your element

```
driver.findElement(By.id("nav-tab-1"));
```

To trigger the javascript dropdown creation and wait for the submenu to be loaded you can use something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("x-menu-el-nav-tab-1")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocatedBy(By.id("nav-tab-1"))).click();
```

Comment: I've just shared the code too and when I tried the answer mentioned by you it gave me the same exception.

Comment: The locator is fine, what is probably wrong is the moment when you look for the element. Is the dropdown menu created by javascript? Then you need to make sure the nav-tab-1 element is actually created by javascript before you search for it.

Comment: To be frank this is a SFDC console app, and i do not know whether this dropdown is created by javascript. Any how if you can help me create the dropdown menu through a code snippet, i'll try that.

Comment: I have added an example for triggering javascript dropdown creation and then waiting until the element is visible. Might be some typo's but your IDE should be able to fix that.